# How to add aliases and imports into my own mix under umbrella application in Elixir?

Tags: elixir, alias, phoenix-framework, ecto

I have an Umbrella application in Elixir.

It has 2 applications in it. One API controller and views, one only Database ( Ecto ) and everything goes with it.

I want to make my own mix file so I can put my aliases and imports in there. It gets very annoying in the `iex` when every time I have to import bucket load of alias and imports before I can test my codes.

I have already made a file with `.iex.exs` and put that under one of the applications root, no lock when I run `iex -S mix`

Here is the content of my mix file:

`db.iex.exs`

`alias Db.{ Repo, Document }`

Here is the folder structure:

[image]

Thanks guys

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The file should be `.iex.exs` not `db.iex.exs`.